# Silex, create a global variable

Tags: php, silex

I need to show a particular file depending on the company you use the app. This file would be displayed using a setting that would DB.

I want to create a variable globally and add this field to use a base Twig template.

```
$app['image'] = $parameter_db;
{{ app.image }}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$app["twig"]->addGlobal("image", $parameter_db);
```

This is a way to assign global variables.

Comment: I need to use throughout the application, I have an error message when rerouting, because there is no variable.

Comment: `$app['image'] = $parameter_db; $app['twig']->addGlobal('image', $app['image']);`?